# i made an sql database to contain player data but there is a problem that i cannot solve

Tags: mariadb

**[Error] Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`SteamID' at line 1**

```
phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.6
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: mysql3.blazingfast.io:3306
-- Erstellungszeit: 29. Mai 2017 um 10:07
-- Server-Version: 10.1.22-MariaDB-1~xenial
-- PHP-Version: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Datenbank: `ByYTimer`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `byyadminactivity`
--

CREATE TABLE `byyadminactivity` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SteamID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Nick` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `LastSeen` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `byyadminactivity`
--


--
-- Indizes der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `byyadminactivity`
--
ALTER TABLE `byyadminactivity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Id_UNIQUE` (`Id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `SteamID_UNIQUE` (`SteamID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT für exportierte Tabellen
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT für Tabelle `byyadminactivity`
--
ALTER TABLE `byyadminactivity`
  MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

i tried to drop the table and re do it and the same thing happened.

the problem lies in Id but i dont have enough skills to solve it.

i searched the entire site for solutions but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error message indicates a problem near the column name SteamID.

Please have a try on the table creation script below

```
CREATE TABLE `byyadminactivity` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SteamID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Nick` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `LastSeen` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `byyadminactivity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Id_UNIQUE` (`Id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `SteamID_UNIQUE` (`SteamID`);

ALTER TABLE `byyadminactivity`
  MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
```

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)[mariadb](/questions/tagged/mariadb)